# Невозможно получить данные таблиц в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, iis

В **Visual Studio**, во вкладке обозреватель серверов есть подключения данных. Однако при попытке прочитать данные получаю ошибку - "**Адресат вызвал исключение**". Вопрос, как можно получить информацию по ошибке, т.е он вызвал это исключение, как его посмотреть.Еще момент напротив базы данных стоит красный крестик - это означает что он не может подключится к данным? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится. Создал в 2015 студии новый проект (пусть WinForm), открыл вкладку серверов, приконектился к своему MsSQL, выбрал базу, открылся список таблиц, выбрал талблицу, выбрал пункт меню "Show Table Data" - и получил в новом окне содержимое таблицы.

Comment: Да естественно, красный крестик отсутствие соединения

Comment: Простите, а как в студии устаналвивается соединение с сервером баз данных?

Comment: Там же в на вкладке серверов в дереве есть ветвь "Data Connections". Ставите на не мышь и по правому клику открываете контекстное меню. Дальше выбираете нужный пункт - допустим "Add Connection" и дальше интерактивной процедуре, за несколько шагов, отвечая на вопросы создаете нужное Вам подключение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть была в том, что в SQL Server Object Explorer присутствовал локальный сервер. Похоже система по умолчанию пыталась приконектиться к нему, но баз данных для рабочего проекта в нем не было. Удалив подключение к локальному серверу и обновив Data Connection в обозревателе серверов проблема была решена.